# Give error to ajax call from controller's catch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, error-handling

I have a jquery ajax call to my controller action.
Now in my controller, it went catch. Now I need to invoke error function of my ajax call. If I throw error, this will work. Is there any other method to invoke error function.

Bye the way, my controller's action's return type is string/void.

Comment: Can you provide code that shows what you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write this in your Action `Throw new HttpException();` This will invoke error to your ajax function and handle it with this $.ajax method function `error:function() {do something }`

Answer (score 4):

I've verified this now, so I'm posting it as an answer. You can throw an exception as @Timur mentioned, but that has overhead associated with it that you may not want/need.

In your action method, you can set `Response.StatusCode` to an error value (anything in the 300, 400, or 500 range), and it will cause jQuery to invoke the error handler instead of the success handler.

Comment: if I'd need to pass an actual error msg using that response you suggested to then display it, say, in an alert, how could I manage that process in the controller and, if you could, how do I catch it in the .js?

Comment: There's also a `Response.StatusDescription` that you can set to whatever string value you'd like. I believe this comes across as the final parameter in jQuery's `error` ajax handler. Also, to amend my original answer, the more correct MVC way of handling all of this is probably to return an `HttpStatusCodeResult` instead of setting values directly on the `Response` object.